# Can i execute anything from RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to call an API from RabbitMQ if time has reached (time is provided in message). I meant to say that does RabbitMQ has any feature to execute linux curl command?

Answer (score 2):

RabbitMQ is message broker. It has no option to execute commannd.
What you may do

- configre time-to-live for your queue https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html
- once TTL value is reached message will be delivered to Dead Letter Exchange https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html
- consume dead messages (use separate consumer), execute curl action when message is consumed. you may write that consumer in any language that has client library for RabbitMQ, see https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html (tutorial 1, Hello World is what you need)

Comment: That i already know. Thankyou for the clarification. Actually i heard from someone but i was not sure so i posted here for clarification. Thanks again.